# Url redirected you too many times. How do I solve it

Tags: .htaccess

After adding last three line of code in .htaccess now on page load I get webpage-url redirected you too many times error.

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 http://example.com/404/errorPage.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
# also tried - RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is this server behind load balancer or reverse proxy?

Comment: I am using shared hosting on gadaddy and change nameserver to cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add `+FollowSymLinks`

So it would be..

```
Options -Indexes
+FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404/errorPage.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Adding +FollowSymLinks gives me internal server error.

Comment: what does your rewritebase look like..and are you trying to redirect to https?

Comment: I am using public root in godaddy and yes I am trying to redirect to https.

Comment: Is the website in your public_html root or sub-directory within public_html?

Comment: Also.... Why do you have a 403 forbidden with 404 error page? You need to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this url [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218890817) at cloudflare that create page rule and this works for me thanx all for your effort.